# how to set the Databse connection string in Web.config file in Asp.Net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic  for exceptions.

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="testEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=ROCKER\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sunny;Password=sunnyconnected;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Test\sqlserver2008;database=test;User ID=sunny;Password=sunnyconnected" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

> This Connection String Set in Root Web.config File then it give runtime Above Mention Error.How it Can be Handle And Set in Asp.Net MVC2.

Comment: You have defined multiple `<connectionStrings>` sections. Combine those to 1 section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**connectionStrings**" section should appear only once in a config file. Check if you have added it twice.